# Start two activities simultaneously one in foreground other in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities **SplashScreen** and **MainActivity**.

MainActvity download some data and show it.

Now I want to start both activities on application start, MainActivity in background and SplashScreen in foreground and when the data of MainActivity download complete I want to make MainActivity foreground and finish SplashScreen.

I have seen many solution but no one is going good in my situation.
Please give me some suggestion or example .

Comment: Why do you need an `Activity` to download data? You can start a background `Thread` or a `Service` or use `AsyncTask`, all of which can download data in the background while your `SplashScreen` entertains your user. When the data is completely downloaded, you can start your `Main`Activity` and tell your `SplashScreen` to finish.

Comment: for this at least we need to start the method/function of data download which is in mainactivity. so question become again same how to start an activity on background.

or there is way to start asynk task without calling its activity i don't know as i started android couple of days ago.If you have a code please send me or link if any for this specific situation @david-wasser

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: You could try searching the Internet with the following keywords: "Android Background Data Download". I'm sure you'll find something. We aren't here to do your work for you.

Comment: yes i know and your given link doing relativily good for me then my previous search and code.I will thnk u when my work is done.Don't be kind of rude i know you are not here to do my work. @david-wasser

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to make splash screen to download data and when it completed show new activity (MainActivity). In onStart metod  use downloaded data stored on phone.

Your example: The only way You can have resolve this your way is by start MainActivity first and from onStart start SplashScreen:

```
class SplashScreen extends Activitiy {

    public void onStart() {
       EventBus.register(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void finishedDownload(FinishedDownloadEvent) {
       this.finish()
    }
} 

class MainActivity extens Activity () {

   public void onStart () {
        open(new Intent(SplashScreen.class)); // We would like to have 

        download();
   }

   public void download (OnFinish onFinish) {
        ... download

       EventBus.post(new FinishedDownloadEvent());
   }
}
```

I forgot:

```
 class EventBus {

    private final static Bus instance = new Bus();

    public static void register (Object obj) {
        instance.register(obj)
    } 

    public static void post (Event obj) {
        instance.post(obj)
    } 

 }
```

[EventBuss](https://github.com/square/otto)

Comment: By this Code will become more messy.As SplashScreen has no coding for downloading data and has only progressDialogue. wherese Mainactivity have fragments and downloading of data and other thing which are going into activity.
so please,please suggest me another way @John Tribe

Comment: My approach is less memory consuming and remember that activities should work as stand alone workers. BTw.  I would create service for downloading data. so it would looks like service.download (new OnFinishCallback()) in SplashScreen and in MainActivity service.getData() that way all logic is encapsulated in my service.

Comment: can u give me some example.
How about starting both activities and `intent.putExtra("something")` and getting it into spalshScreenn where if condition could work when "something" using `intent.getExtra("something");`

will it work or not? @John Tribe

Comment: Im' not sure if understand but if You want to control other other activities from activity I would suggest to use EventBus.

Comment: then please tell me an example to do so.

Comment: if you need i can send you my code of activities..  @john-tribe

Comment: its not resolving EventBus i also add square/otto library in gradle @john-tribe